# Discord Python - Search for regex in message.content and ignore anything before it or after

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    streamables = re.compile(r'streamable(\.com)\/([\w-]{2,50})')
    if streamables.search(message.content) and message.channel.id == 363835464219754498:
        url = message.content
        print(url)
```

I want it to only display the link even if there is something before it or after. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the result of `streamables.search(message.content)` to get the match object, then call `group()` to grab what it matched.

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    streamables = re.compile(r'streamable(\.com)\/([\w-]{2,50})')
    match = streamables.search(message.content)
    if match and message.channel.id == 363835464219754498:
        url = match.group()
        print(url)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hey, what if I want to use replace() in the code? It does not seem to work well: https://hastebin.com/tuledeqebe.py

Comment: @Kzap2 what are you trying to accomplish? For starters, the replace won't work because your match won't contain 'https://' at the start (since you're not including that in your pattern). I'm also not sure what you're expecting to happen with that substitution.

Comment: Nvm, I sorted it out in the end.